# Post Deletion happens only after refresh - subscription activates after refresh and post is removed

Tags: angular, typescript

I am following along with some coursework. So I got the delete function working up to the point where it deletes it from the node server. It's an Angular front end with a mongodb database.

the deletepost in the angular service:

```
deletePost(postId: string) {
        this.http
          .delete('http://localhost:3000/api/posts/' + postId)
          .subscribe(() => {
            console.log('deleted');
            const updatedPosts = this.posts.filter(post => post.id !== 
                  postId);
            this.posts = updatedPosts;
            this.postsUpdated.next([...this.posts]);
       });
     }
```

the angular front end:

```
onDelete(postId: string) {
    console.log('deleted');
    this.postsService.deletePost(postId);
```

What happens is (note the console logs), when you first click the delete console log in the frontend is triggered. But no deletion. Once you refresh the page and try again the second delete console output from the service is triggered and the post is deleted.

the node function:

```
app.delete('/api/posts/:id', (req, res, next) => {
      Post.deleteOne({ _id: req.params.id }).then(result => {
         res.status(200).json({ message: 'Post deleted' });
      });
    });
```

How do I fix this?

Maybe it's not allowing immediate deletion for some reason - Add, Delete right after - is that the case?

Comment: It seems that this is a routine error - upon closer investigation it didn't return the id from the mongo document - how do I return an object from express? I forgot lol

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to the service in the onDelete Method and not in the service.
In the Service return the http Delete Request as an Observable.

Here is some code to understand:
Your DeletePost Method in Service

```
deletePost(postId: string) :Observable<any> {
        return this.http.delete('http://localhost:3000/api/posts/' + postId);
}
```

In your component .ts file:

```
onDelete(postId: string) {
    this.postsService.deletePost(postId).subscribe(()=>{
        console.log("deleted");
  });
}
```

This will both delete the post on Backend and notify you when it is deleted via the console.log. Then you can update your local Post Variable

You can learn more about Observables and Subscription at http://reactivex.io/

Answer (score 0):

OK so it was really the post ID problem - how I got sidetracked and forgot what. But the ID has to be returned from node in the add post request (excerpt):

```
post
    .save()
    .then(addedPost => {
      console.log(addedPost + 'ADD');
      res.status(201).json({
        message: 'Post Added',
        postId: addedPost._id
      });
    })
```

The service then looks like (excerpt):

```
.subscribe(responseData => {
        console.log(responseData.message);
        post.id = responseData.postId;
        this.posts.push(post);
        this.postsUpdated.next([...this.posts]);
      });
```